# configure UICollectionView cell on initial lookup

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am getting cells for a UICollectionView by calling `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`. I want to set some specific configuration information the **first** time my cell is returned from this method and not subsequently when it gets reused. Is there a hook somewhere where I can run "one time" code on collection view cells?

Obviously I could just set this information every time or use a boolean to keep track of whether or not the cell has been initialized, but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner way first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I ended up solving this was to put my own view inside a generic UICollectionViewCell with a view tag. Then, when I go to deque my cell, I pull out the view using viewWithTag. If I get nil back, it's the first time this code has run, so I can init my view using my own constructor normally. This seemed slightly better than keeping track of a boolean in the cell implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy enough to do from within a cell's implementation but there's no convenient way for a data source to differentiate newly created vs reused cells. If your configuration must be supplied by the data source then the data source probably need to check if the cell has been configured already.

The cells will be created once so you can use `init` or `awakeFromNib` to set some initial state. Cells will then have `prepareForReuse` called when being reused allowing you to perform any changes you need to make per-use.